# How to git pull remote and (re)initialize the local project after .git removal?

Tags: git, repository

Hard to explain, but basically I have a cloned remote repository that has had its local `.git` information removed. Some work has been done; but now I need to integrate it back into the remote repo; how do I 'init' the local project with the remote git repo? I know I can `git init` but I do not want to lose history, or commits, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the project once more, then use *cp* or *rsync* command to overwrite all the project files in worktree by what you have modified.

To prevent potential conflict between your local change and remote, after clone the remote, you should create a new local branch and overwrite its worktree with your local modification. then, you merge this local branch with the one tracking the remote.

Comment: After .git removal, there is nothing to do with git, reinitializing a new git repository became inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the SHA of the last commit you had checked out was `abc123`, do the following:

```
git init .
git checkout -b my_branch (where my_branch is a new branch name you made up)
git remote add origin <url of your remote repository>
git fetch
git reset abc123
git commit -am "Here are my changes"
git checkout master (or whatever branch you were on before you deleted .git)
git merge my_branch
```

If you don't know the exact commit you were last on, this will work if you pick any commit that is *before* the actual commit you were last on; the further back you go, the more merge conflicts you will have. Don't pick a commit that happened *after* the the actual commit you were last on, as that will cause you to lose changes.