# How to add git to existing project in multiple places

Tags: git

I have a project in my local and the same version is also in the server. Now I added git to my local project and committed all the files, and pushed the code to the remote.

How can I add git to the project, which is in the server? The local commits (or remote commits) should also be available in the server version of the project.

Comment: Does your server have changes that are not in your local?

Comment: Both the version is exactly same.

Comment: Then why not just `git clone` from remote?

Comment: How do you acces the server? ssh?

Comment: yes with ssh @phd

Comment: @Ashkan because the site is live and I will clone I need to delete the current project and after clone, I need to install all dependencies. I think it will take time and till the completion the site will be down.

Comment: From what I understand, I think this is the same as you have right now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354184/how-to-git-pull-remote-and-reinitialize-the-local-project-after-git-removal

Answer (score 0):

At the server you need to create two new repositories — one in the working tree and one somewhere else; the second one must be bare repository (only .git, lacking a worktree) because pushing is mostly allowed to bare repositories; git oriented towards pull-based workflows. There are ways to push to non-bare reposirtories but I recommend to avoid that.

Add the bare repository as the remote `origin` to your local repository and push. Then at the server pull from the bare repository to non-bare.

Something like:

```
# create repositories at the server
ssh user@server "
cd /path/to/non-bare &&
git init &&
cd /path/to/bare.git &&
git init --bare
" &&

# add remote and push
git remote add origin user@server:/path/to/bare.git &&
git push origin master &&

# at the server pull from bare to non-bare
ssh user@server "
cd /path/to/non-bare &&
git pull /path/to/bare.git master
"
```

The last one could be automated using [a server-side hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+to+deploy+hook) but you better do things manually to learn and then automate.